# common lisp type vector of fixnums

Tags: vector, types, lisp, common-lisp, type-declaration

In Common Lisp I can check a type like:

```lisp
(typep #(1 2 3) 'sequence)
;; returns T
```

And so I can use `sequence` in `(declaim (ftype ...` to specify a parameter of a function.

Is it possible to make the type even more specific and force a parameter to be a `vector` from `fixnum`?

Example:

```lisp
(declaim (ftype (function (fixnum) sequence) abc))

(defun abc (n) #(n))
```

This function and its type definition works as expected. But can I define the return type more specific? Instead of `sequence` something like `(vector fixnum)`?

Comment: Note that `(defun abc (n) #(n))` does not return a `(vector fixnum)`, but a `(vector symbol)`  -> which usually will be a `(vector t)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Possible type declarations for vectors**

The Common Lisp HyperSpec provides an overview of [type specifiers](https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/04_bc.htm).

We can follow through the table there to the *system class* [vector](https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_vector.htm).
This tells us that we can use `vector` as a *Compound Type Specifier*:

```
vector [{element-type | *} [{size | *}]]
```

Above is a syntax definition.

So declarations can use `vector` types like:

```
(vector)              ; any vector
(vector *)            ; any vector 
(vector * *)          ; any vector
(vector fixnum *)     ; vector of fixnums of any size
(vector * 42)         ; vector of length 42
(vector fixnum 42)    ; vector of fixnums and vector length 42
```

If you move the class chain upwards, you can see that the system class [sequence](https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_seq.htm#sequence) does not provide such a syntax.

**Note on *returning a vector***

If you write `(defun abc (n) #(n))`, then it won't return the argument, but the symbol n. Elements of a *literal* vector are not evaluated.

```
CL-USER 24 > (defun abc (n) #(n))
ABC
```

Above returns a literal vector of a symbol. *literal* also means that you should not modify it.

```
CL-USER 25 > (abc 42)
#(N)
```

There is a backquote syntax for vectors:

```
CL-USER 26 > (defun abc (n) `#(,n))
ABC

CL-USER 27 > (abc 42)
#(42)
```

We can also call the function `vector`, which will create a vector with the argument values as its contents.

```
CL-USER 28 > (defun abc (n) (vector n))
ABC

CL-USER 29 > (abc 42)
#(42)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write

```
(coerce #(1 2 3) '(vector fixnum))
```

Or, more generally, use `make-array` to specify the type:

```
(make-array 3 :element-type 'fixnum :initial-contents '(1 2 3))
```

Note that the element type in arrays is an information mostly used between Lisp and the implementation platform, to *possibly* use a specialized type of array that is more compact, more efficient, etc. and not a type that necessarily restrict what kind of value you can put inside.

For example, a vector as follows:

```
(make-array 10 :element-type '(member 1 2 3))
```

is described in SBCL has having the following type:

```
Element type: (UNSIGNED-BYTE 2)
```

But is initialized with zeroes:

```
#(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
```

But zero is not a value of the declared type.

It all boils down to what the upgraded-element-type of the array is, which is the type of value that can fit in the specialized array.

Comment: That's about creating things which can hold objects of a type, not declaring types.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Oh right, I read a bit too fast

Comment: Though it's always good to remember that one does not necessarily gets exactly the types requested, which can make type handling for strings/vectors a bit tricky...